# How to organize C++ CMake codebase to build and include libraries but keep IDE debuggability features?

Tags: c++, cmake

Hi I am trying to decompose a C++ codebase (CMake with MSVC Generator).

I am taking sets of modules and creating libraries where code is shared.

The libraries are building .lib files in an install output directory with an include folder for the header files. (install step is copying them over)

The problem is that the consuming project loses link to original header file and the corresponding cpp file. This causes us to lose some nice IDE features.

For example, Ctrl-K+O does not swap hpp/cpp in Visual Studio anymore.

Additionally, we would like to edit header file from library if we see an issue but the copy in the include folder is not the true source file from the repository.

Is there a way to structure a large C++ codebase to both get libraries and debug features like knowledge of the source file locations in the IDE.

Comment: Using `add_subdirectory` to add everything to a single solution, at least given some cmake options, is not an option, I guess? There are ways to avoid building/installing everything in one go, if that's the only concern preventing you from doing this. Other alternatives probably require hacks that may not work reliably. (Afaik the functionality you're looking for is only available, if the sources/headers aren't part of the solution.)

Comment: Are you using `CMakeSettings.json`? And opening the project using `Open Folder`, then selecting your `CMakeLists.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is an old question, but for any reference now, the following steps work with me:

1. Make sure `CMakeLists.txt` builds successfully, with libraries headers on the path, e.g. using `target_include_directories`.
2. Copy the libraries `.pdb` files to the debug output directory.
3. Select the `Debug` configuration when building the project from Visual Studio, and build it using usual Visual Studio menus.
4. In the Visual Studio toolbars, make sure you select your built debug `.exe` from the `Select Startup Item`.
5. Debug as usual (add breakpoints and hit F5), stepping into a dependency library API will open the corresponding library source file from the directory on which the `.pdb` was built, presumed to be on your local machine.